# Nativescript CSS Text In front of image

Tags: android, css, mobile, nativescript

How to create CSS to make position label in front of image. Like z-index on HTML. I was use background-image, but not working. 
I was create with this code :

```
<grid-layout rows="220, auto" columns="*, *, *" id="cardReport" style="background-image: url('{{ foto }}');">
    <image src="{{ foto }}" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0" tap="goReport"/>
    <label text="{{ namapaket }}" class="info" textWrap="true" row="1" colSpan="1"
           horizontalAlignment="center"/>
</grid-layout>
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the label on the same row as the image.

```
<grid-layout rows="220, auto" columns="*, *, *" id="cardReport" style="background-image: url('{{ foto }}');">
<image src="{{ foto }}" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0" tap="goReport"/>
<label text="{{ namapaket }}" class="info" textWrap="true" row="0" colSpan="1"
       horizontalAlignment="center"/>
```

Comment: Works. Thanks @bradMartin

Answer (score 0):

2023 - NativeScript 8.4.7:

```
<GridLayout rows="*, auto" cols="*">
    <Image [src]="image" stretch="aspectFill" row="0" col="0"></Image>
    <Label [text]="imageText" textWrap="true" row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
</GridLayout>
```